# Handling custom input in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to write a method having four input parameters,all the input parameters are not mandatory. I need to check whether the input parameter is not null and query the database to return the result. Is der any way to do this without checking for all possible combinations... Its like a search engine.. If u give all the input parameters it will give u the exact result else nearest possible result.
For eg,

input(city,customer,name,zip)

if zip is not equal to null and all other fields are null query the database and return values corresponding to zip. It will be list of customers in the entire area based on the zip.If  all the fields are present it will give the exact result. I know that i can check each value and write the query in a conditional loop for all possible combinations to get the result. But i think its a dirty fix..

Thanks..

Comment: Please provide further details, what exactly is your question? Any code?

Comment: How are you querying database? What you suggest is not a dirty hack, it may be the easiest way of achieving what you want.

Comment: + Are there any mandatory parameters or all of them are optional?

Comment: Its like a search engine.. If u give all the input parameters it will give u the exact result else nearest possible result..

Comment: give us some code to work on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of examining all the possible combinations, compose your query dynamically:

```
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder("select foo.* from Foo foo where 1 = 1");
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
if (x != null) {
    q.append(" and foo.x = ?");
    parameters.add(x);
}
if (y != null) {
    q.append(" and foo.y = ?");
    parameters.add(y);
}

// ...
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(q.toString());
int i = 1;
for (String arg : arguments) {
    stmt.setString(i, arg);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a sligtly different proposal:

```
if (city == null) city="*";
if (customer == null) customer="*";
if (name== null) name="*";
if (zip== null) zip="*";
String s = "SELECT * FROM point WHERE city="+city+" customer =" +customer 
     +"name="+name+"zip="+zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you work on a system where you build the text of your request depending on the values of your parameters:

(I've not done MySql for a while so it might not be correct)

```
String s = "SELECT * FROM point "+(x != null || y!= null)? 
"WHERE "+
(x!= null)?+"x="+x:""
(y!= null)?+"y="+y:""
:
"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using optional parameter you may overloade the method using a signature which doesn't require the parameter.

for instance:

```
String input(x,y,z){
     String s = "SELECT * FROM point ......";
     return s;
}

String input(x,y,z,a){
     ...
     str = input(x,y,z,a) + "Where condition...";
     .....
     return s;
}
```

understood the concept?

Comment: Overloading doesnot solve my problem since all my datatypes are String values and i cannot check the name of the parameter...

Comment: oh yes.. understand... then u have no better choise than analyse tem one to one.I propose yo a sligtly different implementation form yhe others.. no... i do anther post... it's easyer

Answer (score 0):

you should check the  operator ...

```
public void input(String... params) {
    String queryBegin = "insert into testtable(testvalue) values('";
    String queryEnd = "');";


    for(String param : params) {
          String fullQuery = queryBegin + param + queryEnd;
        //execute your query
    }

}
```

you have to implement logic to avoid sql injection